# Ruby iterator practice

Tags: ruby, iterator

I am currently learning Ruby and I am wondering whether you guys can suggest some medium to difficult iterators to implemet?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "iterators"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are http://rubyquiz.com/ and more generic http://projecteuler.net/. You will find different exercises in them that you can solve using iterators, recursion, or something else.

Comment: thats it. just th esite that i want

Answer (score 0):

Try mastering Enumerable.inject.  It's a really helpful method that reduces LOC.